# adding a normal CCSprite to CCSpriteBatchNode crashes

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, ccspritebatchnode

I am getting this exception in logs

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'CCSprite is not using the same texture id'
```

What I am trying to do is adding a normal "myfile.png" file to a `SpriteBatchNode`

**declaration of batch node

```
CCSpriteBatchNode *_backgroundLayer = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"sprites.png"];
```

** usage

This line works perfect

```
CCSprite *sprite1 = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"PngFileKeptInSpriteSheet.png"];
[_backgroundLayer addChild:sprite1];
```

But, when I use a direct *.png file to add to batch node, It crashes

```
    CCSprite *sprite2 = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"myfile.png"];
```

crashes on line

```
        [_backgroundLayer addChild:sprite2];
```

On further debugging I found that:

The assertion failure is in file `CCSpriteBatchNode.m`

inside method `-(void) addChild:(CCSprite*)child z:(NSInteger)z tag:(NSInteger) aTag`

at line `NSAssert( child.texture.name == textureAtlas_.texture.name, @"CCSprite is not using the same texture id");`

P.S. : by "normal" I mean not taken from *.plist file

Comment: What version of cocos2d?

Comment: COCOS2D_VERSION 0x00010001

Comment: So is that 1.1 or are you a compiler?

Comment: oops! sorry... it is cocos2d v1.0.1

Comment: is this a new app? If do I strongly suggest moving to v2 or v3.

Comment: Old code... Is higher version backward compatible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First and foremost, I'd update cocos2D. However, that isn't your problem and probably isn't "fixed" in the latest version anyway. This isn't really a bug

Batch nodes require that all the sprites that you intend to batch are using the same texture. When you load a sprite sheet, it uses one, large texture. When you call `spriteWithFile`, cocos2d creates a texture from that image.

It's rare that you'll want to create a batch node from a sprite using `spriteWithFile`. The only scenario I can think of is when you want to draw the same image many times. (Rather than many images from the same texture).

In short, what you are trying to do is unsupported and doesn't make much sense anyway as the two sprites wouldn't be batchable.

Comment: Thanks for the response... I was just trying to avoid the hassle of recreating a a sprite sheet for adding a single new button.

Comment: Though not satisfied... Closing it here... Will add the button normal way not using what previous dev has done. Thanks buddy.

Comment: Do you use a program to make your sprite sheets? There's no too much hassle involved in adding a sprite.

Comment: Yes, The Texture Packer